# Simulate click event in React with TypeScript material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm rendering some material-ui TextFields. By manually typing the value inside it, it'll work properly. It is using handleChange() (change) and handleBlur() (autosave) to handle those events. but the scenario is I have to update the value not by manually typing but from the store.

So, if I pass the value from the store, it is not actually updating the value unless I click inside the field and click away or tab out. the value is showing inside the field but not invoking handleChange() and handleBlur() which are the only way to update the value inside. Also I have to type at least a value.

Approach:

I set an onFocus to the field and on it's handleFocus, I'm trying to either simulating click() and blur() or calling handleClick() and handleBlur(). If I simulate a click event,

> ***Uncaught TypeError: element.click is not a function***

If I try to call handleChange() and handleBlur()

[image]

```
  readonly refO: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

  constructor(props: InputProps) {
    super(props);
    this.refO = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  }

...
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          inputRef={this.refO}
          id={this.labelId}
          required={required}
          label={label}
          error={error}
          value={this.setValue()}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={handleChange}
          disabled={disabled}
          fullWidth
          type={type}
          InputLabelProps={InputLabelProps}
          InputProps={{ className: cx({ [classes.modified]: isModified }) }}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
        />
```

What can I do inside handleFocus() in order to achieve this. or the proper approach to achieve this. I'm very new to TypeScript. is my approach wrong or any other way to overcome this.

```
  handleFocus = (element: HTMLInputElement) => {
   element.click();
   this.props.handleChange();
   this.props.handleBlur();
  }
```

PS: cannot add more code due to some sensitivity issues.

Comment: Can you please setup your environment inside https://codesandbox.io? It will be much faster to help you there (you can do that without typescript, once this work you can move to ts).

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue.

i knew it has to be done from inside the handleFocus. but what i was doing call other event handlers from it. then i thought why should i. the function has been invoked so just update the values from it.

```
 handleFocus = (value) => {
  //  update my value
 }
```

it's unconventional but all we require is the result.

ps: i even pinged few people on twitter(this has put our reputation on the stake. it was a race against time). i was that desperate. i apolagize to them.